# Using goodness of fit statistics to cluster data

Tags: linear-regression, clustering, multivariate-statistical-analysis

We are working on a wrapper that clusters observations, wrapping around a multivariate linear regression model within each cluster of observations. The idea is to use some goodness of fit statistic like $R^2$ to move observations to other clusters where the linear models gives better $R^2$ values.

We can't find much on using $R^2$ or other statistics of linear models, to cluster data.

My question is if we missed something in fundamental statistics that makes this idea terrible?

Comment: I think stats.stackexchange is better suited for this question.